# php select records from database

Tags: php, mysql

Need help :

I have 4 columns in css/html, and I need to show records from database (100 records) based on id number ( or sorted rows) with the following configuration :

Column1.......Column2......Column3......Column4

....id-1..............id-2..............id-3...............id-4

....id-5..............id-6..............id-7...............id-8

....id-9..............id-10............id-11..............id-12

....id-13.............id-14...........id-15.............id-16

and so on.

From 100 records, every column will have 25 rows respectively.

The problems is comes from the rule that Column1 should be first filled Out, then continued to the next column.

How can I use php if condition to do that rule?

I have tried and found confused :

```
 <?php 
             $row=0;
             foreach ($ads as $ad) { 
             $row++;
             if (($row==1) or ($row%4==0)) {
             ?>
            <div  style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width: 200px; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal; padding: 3px; text-align: justify; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #ffe">
                <a href="#"><?php echo $ad['id']; ?>. <?php echo $ad['adds']; ?> </a><br>
                <span ><strong>contact: <?php echo $ad['phone1']; ?>, <?php echo $ad['phone2']; ?>, <?php echo $ad['phone3']; ?></strong></span>
            </div>
            <?php 
            $row=0;
            }} ?>
```

I need to select record number 1, 5, 7, 13 and so on. Then continue to second column.

Comment: Have you tried anything, anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to select record number 1, 5, 7, 13 and so on.

Why don't you use a `for` loop and increment the iteration variable by the number of columns on every iteration?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i += 4) {
    $ad = $ads[$i];
    // print cell
}
```

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer als "accepted answer" if it solved your problem, by clicking the outline of the check icon next to it.